# Kiosk Mode - Browser Full Screen - Restrict everything else except the opened window

Tags: browser, fullscreen

I am working on asp.net application which is used in one specific machine. On launching this website, the website will be opened in full screen. Now, I should restrict user to use only this window. I should not allow user to open any window, app, anything else by keyboard, mouse.

Please help me in designing this.

Thanks,
Fayaz

Answer (score 0):

Some trial and error helped me. Posting here so that would be helpful for who are looking for same...

Quoting from http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1858713,00.asp

You can lock down these subversive key combinations using restrictions in the Registry. Launch RegEdit from the Start menu's Run dialog; navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
Policies\Microsoft Internet Explorer\Restrictions; and find or create each of the following DWORD values, setting its data to 1 to enable the restriction:

NoBrowserClose (disables closing the browser window)
NoBrowserContextMenu (disables right-click context menu)
NoFileOpen (disables use of Ctrl-O or Ctrl-L to launch an arbitrary URL)
NoOpenInNewWnd (disables opening a link in a new window via Ctrl-N or Shift-click)
And below url helps in blocking other functionality

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/28/how-to-setup-assigned-access-in-windows-8-1-kiosk-mode.aspx